# Checking a C# property without a reference to its class?

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class 'App' which has instances of both a 'DeviceManager' class and a windows form 'MainForm' stored as fields.
MainForm is made visible by clicking a system tray icon. DeviceManager has Docked and Undocked methods, with Docked starting a synchronization operation. The Docked method should only start the operation if the MainForm is not visible.

DeviceManager doesn't have access to App's members, so it can't use App's reference to MainForm to check the form's status. Having App pass itself into DeviceManager's constructor seems like a lot of coupling when DeviceManager has no other need for such a reference (MainForm and DeviceManager are thus far unaware of each other).

I'm now considering having the setter of the App.IsUserActive property raise an event that DeviceManager can use to maintain its own 'IsUserActive' field.

Are there any other approaches I could look into?

Edit: added code to illustrate:

```
internal class App
{
    private DeviceManager _deviceMgr;
    private MainForm _mainForm;

    internal App()
    {
        _deviceMgr = new DeviceManager();
        _mainForm = new MainForm { Visible = false };
    }
}

internal class DeviceManager
{
    private void Docked()
    {
        if (!_mainForm.Visible) //can't see MainForm or App from here
        {
            Connect();
            StartSynchronization();  
        }
    }

    private void Undocked()
    {
        Disconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to understand your question if you *showed* representative code rather than *describing* it.

Comment: That sounds right.  You could also make another class they both have references to that stores the data, but that is just as tightly coupled in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

There is a global reference to the forms you can use.
Here's a quick example:

```
//Inside of DeviceManager class
private bool CheckFormVisibility<TForm>() where TForm : Form
{
    TForm form = System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms.OfType<TForm>().SingleOrDefault();
    return form != null && form.Visible;
}
```

Then call `CheckFormVisibility<MyForm>()` or remove the generics and use specifically for your `MyForm`.

**I'm going under the assumption here that you will only have zero/one instance of a form.

Comment: Nice answer from a knowledge of the API.  However, it is important to note that from a design perspective there is no difference between using a global (like this) and strongly coupling the classes.  IN FACT, I would argue this is worse because you can't easily see a class is being used and could introduce regression errors easily.  The OQ event based model is much easier to maintain, IMHO